# I want to extract size and position in the YAML file and store as a bounding box for the categories. I have no idea and help me go about solving

Tags: python, yaml

in the following image, I have to extract size and position as bounding box for categories like GROUP_INVD and GROUP_INVN
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdE5s.jpg)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can read yaml for example with the [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) module

eg by using:

```
import yaml

with open('filename') as file:
    yaml_dict = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

you then get a python object which you can use to create your bounding box.